# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and it has only ideals $\{0\}$ and $R$ itself, then $R$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am studying Ring theory and I came up with a well known theorem which is like that

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and it has only ideals $\{0\}$ and $R$ itself. Then $R$ is a field. I will attach a image of the proof of this theorem.

So basically what usual proof runs is that just take a non-zero element $a$ from $R$ and if we get a multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $R-\{0\}$ ,i.e. we must to find an element $b\ne0 $ in $R$ such that $ab=1$ then we are done.

Now my question is that we need to proof that $R$ is field so we need to show that the non-zero elements of $R$ forms an Abelian group under multiplication$(i.e. $ commutative division ring$)$. But the usual proofs does not talk about closure property. If $a$ and $b$ be two non-zero elements of $R$ then it may happen that $ab=0$$($ If $R$ contains zero divisor $)$. So it may happen that closure property doesn’t hold in some case. How to deal with this problem? Any help or hint will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

A usual proof of the stated theorem looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You are misreading the closure property. $0$ is in the ring so there's no violation of closure when the sum or product of two elements happens to be $0$.

Comment: Suppose that $a \neq 0 \neq b$, but $ab = 0$. What are the sets $aR$ and $bR$?

Comment: @EthanBolker We need to show that $R$ is commutative divison ring which menas $(R-\{0\},.)$ is a commutative group and hence if we take two non-zero elements and product them it must be non-zero (closure). But if a ring has zero divisor then this closure property doesn’t hold.

Comment: See the comment from @Jay .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the specific details of the question, we have the more general fact:

> Let $R$ be a **nonzero** commutative ring with $1$. Suppose that for every $a \in R \setminus \{0\}$, there exists $a' \in R$ with $aa' = 1$.
> Then, $R$ is a field.

Firstly, note that $a'$ above must necessarily be nonzero since $1 \neq 0$ by hypothesis. Moreover, this $a'$ has to be unique, and we can denote this by $a^{-1}$. (You can prove this without already assuming that $R \setminus \{0\}$ is closed under multiplication.)

Now you want to show that if $a, b \neq 0$, then $ab \neq 0$. But if $ab = 0$, then multiplying with $a^{-1}$ and then $b^{-1}$ shows that $1 = 0$, a contradiction.

---

To conclude, every nonzero element having an inverse also implies that the set of nonzero elements is closed under multiplication.

Comment: This solution is perfect. I really don’t know why there was a downvote :)